# getPackageName for a different module

Tags: android, package

I'm having two modules in my project. Both the modules have different package names. I'm using the second module as a library. The problem is, when I use `getPackageName()` in this second module, it returns me the package name of the first module.

How to resolve that?

Comment: `getPackageName()` returns the package name which you have defined in your manifeast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was simple. Using `getClass().getPackage().toString()` returned me the package name of the current class and hence the current module.